# how to create webshare in a asp.net web application?

Tags: asp.net, web-folders

We want to offer some file storage capability in our asp.net 3.5 web app and would like users to create web folders by mapping to a particular URL [hosted on our IIS]. this will allow users to simply copy files from their systems to the mapped web folder and save them the task of uploading files, etc. Any ideas on how we can implement a webshare capability on webserver would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

What about FTP (FTPS)? In [FTP Publishing service](http://www.iis.net/extensions/ftp) (ISS7 Extension) you can write your own authentication provider based on .NET Membership, or you can use same provider, which you are using in you web application. You can also extend the built-in functionality of this sevice to customize it's functions.

If you want to make an user interface in asp.net site, you can use System.IO classes to manage files.

Comment: i dont want to make a user interface. I want the users to be able to be simply open the web share in their normal windows explorer or may be even map a drive to webshare.

Comment: so than use FTP publishing service. It is simple to map a folder in "Network places" in Windows to a ftp. Mapping it to drive is much more complicated. You can use program like WebDrive to map an ftp connection to drive or you musst open Samba ports and change system settings to make it possible to connect over public network. But Samba sharing is using only Windows authentication.

Comment: i just found out that i can use WebDAV protocol to enable this kind of functionality. Just need to work my head around forms authentication with that.

Comment: What version of IIS do you have?

Comment: I have IIS 6 as of now but will be soon moving to IIS7